# OpenTelemetry export to ElasticAPM

Tags: open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I'm running the OpenTelemetry demo (webshop) on localhost:8080 and want to push data to ElasticAPM. I've also set up the APM Server.

This is my otelcol-configj-extras.yml file:

exporters:
otlp:
endpoint: http://localhost:9200

service:
pipelines:
traces:
receivers: [otlp]
processors: [batch]
exporters: [otlp]

And this is the apm-server.yml:

output.elasticsearch:
hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

I'm not receiving any data from the demo application.

I expected data to show up in ElasticAPM. But there is no data.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is instructing the otel collector to export directly to elasticsearch.  If you haven't modified `apm-server.yml` to listen on a non-default address it will be on `localhost:8200`.  You should be able to update your `otelcol-configj-extras.yml`  to:

```yaml
exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: localhost:8200
    # uncomment the following if TLS is not enable in APM Server
    # tls:
    #   insecure: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've updated the otelcol-config-extras.yml like you said. Unfortunately there is still no data in Elastic-APM. Why are there 2 different ports in apm-server.yml by default? app-server: host: "127.0.0.1:8200" and output.elasticsearch:hosts: ["localhost:9200"].

Comment: `apm-server.host: 127.0.0.1:8200` (note: `apm-` not `app-`) specifies the listen address for apm-server, where it will receive data from the otel collector.  `output.elasticsearch:hosts` instructs apm-server to write data to that elasticsearch cluster.  I'd suggest [turning on debug logging](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md) in the otel collector to ensure it's reaching apm-server.  apm-server should be logging serious issues by default.